# torsocks not working in El Capitan

Tags: homebrew, macos, tor

Just a few weeks ago on OS X Yosemite, it worked fine. Now, after performing a clean install of OS X El Capitan it no longer works. I’m very inclined to believe something in El Capitan is the culprit since it doesn’t work on two different computers *but* I can get it to work right now by doing it in a Yosemite VM guest inside an El Capitan host.

Using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), I install `tor` and `torsocks`:

```
brew install tor torsocks
```

Installation goes fine. I then copy over the sample `torrc` and add `ExitNodes`

```
cp "$(brew --prefix)/etc/tor/torrc.sample" "$(brew --prefix)/etc/tor/torrc"
echo 'ExitNodes {es}' >> "$(brew --prefix)/etc/tor/torrc"
```

I start `tor`

```
tor &
```

Everything goes OK

```
Oct 16 01:18:50.101 [notice] Tor v0.2.6.10 (git-58c51dc6087b0936) running on Darwin with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2d and Zlib 1.2.5.
Oct 16 01:18:50.101 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Oct 16 01:18:50.102 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc".
Oct 16 01:18:50.104 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Oct 16 01:18:50.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/local/Cellar/tor/0.2.6.10/share/tor/geoip.
Oct 16 01:18:50.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/local/Cellar/tor/0.2.6.10/share/tor/geoip6.
Oct 16 01:18:50.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Oct 16 01:18:50.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
Oct 16 01:18:50.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Oct 16 01:18:50.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
Oct 16 01:18:51.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Oct 16 01:18:52.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Oct 16 01:18:52.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
```

Then I try to use `torsocks` to check if everything is fine

```
torsocks curl -s https://check.torproject.org | grep Congratulations
```

No message, which means it isn’t working. I also try to check my IP

```
torsocks curl http://ipecho.net/plain
```

It confirms it isn’t working, by showing my real IP.

I also tried various other commands and apps, as well as different `ExitNodes` (including none at all) and different configurations. Nothing seems to do the trick. It works correctly on Yosemite, and I do nothing differently. Since there isn’t an actual error shown, this is difficult to diagnose.

As a further note (not sure how relevant it is), `torsocks show` outputs

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=""
```

And here are the `Dependencies` part of `brew info tor`

```
==> Dependencies
Required: libevent ✔, openssl ✔
Optional: libnatpmp ✘, miniupnpc ✘, libscrypt ✘
```

and `brew info torsocks`

```
==> Dependencies
Build: autoconf ✔, automake ✔, libtool ✔
```

To note that `torsocks` is the one that doesn’t work. `tor` by itself does, [when configured in System Preferences](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212586/tor-and-torsocks-not-working-in-el-capitan?noredirect=1#comment256906_212586). This can also be confirmed with `curl`, by doing `curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 http://ipecho.net/plain`.

Comment: Does TorSocks need DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES

Comment: @Mark No idea, hence why I stated I don’t know how relevant it is. The value is the same under Yosemite and El Capitan, though, so likely not the cause.

Comment: I have the same problem, it's still working on my other Macbook with Yosemite, but doesn't work on this one running OSX El Capitan. `Tor` works, I've confirmed. But `Torsocks` doesn't.

Comment: @Sheharyar Which steps have you taken to confirm `tor` really is working?

Comment: Start `tor`. Open any browser, and change proxy to 127.0.0.1:9050 (using plugins or by changing settings in System Preferences). Visit http://check.torproject.org/. If tor's working, it'll tell you.

Comment: Thank you. Confirmed as well it works. Will update the question.

Comment: @Sheharyar I also cannot get it to work with `proxychains-ng` (though I never tried it on Yosemite, it should work by default with `tor`). Can you?

Comment: @Sheharyar There's a bounty if you want to answer this in the answer section :-)

Comment: Related: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9437/how-to-figure-out-why-torsocks-isnt-working-on-os-x

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem doesn't appear to be in "tor" or "torsocks". The problem seems to be in the version of "curl" shipped with El Capitan.

Similar to yourself if I try `torsocks curl -s https://check.torproject.org | grep Congratulations` I get nothing back.

However if I try `torsocks wget -qO- https://check.torproject.org | grep Congratulations` I get the expected replies.

```
  Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.
  Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.
```

But if you install curl from brew (resulting in a newer version of curl than ships with El Capitan) and then run `torsocks /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.45.0/bin/curl -s https://check.torproject.org | grep Congratulations`, you get the expected "Congratulations" messages (note the version number might be different by the time you try this).

```
  Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.
  Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.
```

Comment: Thank you. That would explain why [`proxychains-ng` also does not work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212586/torsocks-not-working-in-el-capitan/218029#comment263058_212586). I wonder that the exact issue is with this particular `curl` version.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this answer isn't quite right. It wasn't the new version of curl in brew that got torsocks working, its that torsocks cant DYLD_INSERT into a system binary on El Capitan due to SIP. System-curl is a system binary. pointing torsocks to a curl it can inject into is what made it work :)

Comment: since i am using lots of http2 protocols, i had to install and configure `curl-openssl` via brew, which caused me the troubles inconjunction with torsocks. using `curl` via brew went smooth